# How do I get snap out of my $PATH?

Tags: snap, paths

When I `echo $PATH` the output ends in ...`/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

I had an ugly breakup with snap after a brief flirtation, how can I get it out of my $PATH?

Comment: Remove snap altogether to have the path removed automatically, if you have an ugly breakup

Comment: @vanadium I did, it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be an edit of the /etc/environment file.